# Como puedo hacer un mapa con marcadores en d3js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy tratando de hacer un mapa de cuba interactivo. Con marcadores. Tengo una imagen del mapa cuba en formato svg dividido en provincias. Le puedo hacer sus hover y todo.vpero necesito hacer marcadores en algunas provincias y no sé cómo hacerlo. Tengo librerías como leaftlet y d3js. Pudieran ayudarme con un ejemplo básico o algún vídeo que conozcan de Youtube donde expliquen eso.
Tengan en cuenta que mi mapa lo cargo de forma local con una imagen que tengo guardada. Y cargo el código svg en el html. En Ksi todos los ejemplos y en chatgpt lo hacen cargando un mapa de Google. Por lo que el mío no tiene coordenadas de mapa real como tal.